# What is the difference between object and node in Maya (scripting)?

Tags: python, list, object, maya, difference

This question may sound silly I know, but I would like to know exactly what is the difference and in which way the hierarchy works in their case.

If I create for instance a **polyCylinder** and bind it to a variable

```
exVar = cmds.polyCylinder(name='cylinder_01')
```

And now I print **exVar**, I get a list with two Unicode string items: one for the name of the object and another one for the name of the node.

```
[u'cylinder_01', u'polyCylinder1']
```

If I go to the *Outliner* I just can see cylinder_01, I cannot see the *polyCylinder1* item.

What do they mean? Is there any way to visualize them in the Outliner or the Hypergraph?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cylinder_01` is the transform, which handles translation, rotation, scale, etc.

`polyCylinder1` is the shape, which holds the vertices, polygons, shader connections, etc.

The shape is parented to the transform. You can see it in the Outliner if you select **Display > Shapes**